# what is the best jquery old typewriter with blink sign in front of text?

Tags: jquery-plugins, text, effect

what is the best jquery old typewriter with blink sign in front of text ?

i found the below link for that :

http://www.labs.skengdon.com/typewriter/

but it has 3 problem :

1-does not support break line / how can i do that ...

2-changing it's speed causes a bad effect ...

3-does n't have blink sign

thanks in future advance

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Out: http://webdev.stephband.info/jticker/ 
Although i never used it.